# Non trivial summation

Tags: summation

I want to do the following summation over `m` going from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Here $x$ is the position, $t$ is the time, $v_F$ and $v_h$ are velocities, $\beta$ is $1/kT$ (the inverse temperature ) and $Q$ is a real number.

[image]

The answer I am expecting to get is this.

[image]

Can somebody tell me how do I carry out this summation so that I get the answer.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you at least give us the summation in Mathematica code?

Comment: I have tried the following:

Sum[(-1)^m Sqrt[
  Abs[(x - vF t) - I m  \[Beta] vF]]/((x - vF t) - 
   I m  \[Beta] vF) (Abs[(x - vh t) - I m  \[Beta] vh])^-(Q + 1/
     2) (Abs[(x + vh t) + 
     I m  \[Beta] vh])^-(Q), {m, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, t \[Element] Reals, vh > 0, 
   vF > 0, \[Beta] > 0, Q \[Element] Reals}]